# How do I access configuration variables from my Bootstrap in ZF?

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, timezone

I just wanted to load a different timezone for my application depending on a configuration variable, so I added this method to my Bootstrap:

```
protected function setTimeZone () {     
    date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
}
```

But I'm stuck while trying to load $timezone from the variable named "timezone" in my configs/application.ini file, where I have this:

```
timezone = "America/Argentina/Cordoba"
```

Any idea, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$config = $this->getOptions();
date_default_timezone_set($config['timezone']);
```

Or you may be able to set the timezone directly from the application config with:

```
phpSettings.date.timezone = "America/Argentina/Cordoba"
```

Comment: Yeah, that's right, I've used the second approach for this specific issue, but the first one seems very usefull and I'll have it in mind, thanks!